# JPA Criteria analog to Hibernate Criteria Alias

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

Let's say I have type `User` which contains object of class `Tenant` with property `Name`.

I want to select from database Users, whose Tenant contains given Name.

In Hibernate Criteria I can simply achieve this goal using alias.

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .createAlias("tenant", "tenant")
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("tenant.name", "sampleTenant") )
    .list();
```

How can I do same with JPA Criteria ?

Thank you for help.

Comment: It really helps if you post your entity (model) classes showing their annotations, then people like me trying to figure out the same thing know if we're at the right place, thanks for considering it.

Comment: Are there any other responses to this question? Weird that no one has answered it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `User` is in a to-one relationship with `Tenant`:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);
cq = cq.where(cb.equal(root.join("tenant").get("name"), "sampleTenant"));
em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to use Aliases. You simply performed the right join, but the question was about how to specify Aliases (if we need them).

Comment: The question was: 'I want to select from database Users, whose Tenant contains given Name'. The solution with Hibernate Criteria (apparently) involves using an alias. The solution with Criteria API does not.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But you should have clarified that Aliases are not used for this purpose in JPA Criteria API. The exact answer is: "You don't need the alias when you use Criteria API, just use the type-safe objects to reference the properties you are interested." https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1045112

Answer (score -1):

i am using below to get the session and rest is same starting from session

```
Session session = ((Session)entityManager.getDelegate());
```

You can explore [JPA CriteriaBuilder](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm)

Comment: so you are not using JPA Criteria then (you're using the Session and Hibernate Criteria), yet the question explicitly asks for JPA Criteria ...